# Используя CSS-счетчики, создать следующие списки:

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #461cff;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>На великій сковороді розішруйте рослину олію</li>
  <!-- 1     -->
  <li>У великій мисці змішайте інгрідієнти:
    <!-- 2     -->
    <ol>
      <li>5 тертих картоплин</li>
      <!-- 2.1   -->
      <li>2 яйця</li>
      <!-- 2.2   -->
      <li>1 цибуля </li>
      <!-- 2.3   -->
      <li>3 ст.л борошна</li>
      <!-- 2.4   -->
      <li>сіль і перець за смаком</li>
      <!-- 2.5   -->

    </ol>
  </li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A dolore minima, placeat praesentium quos rem suscipit? Aut cum cumque et hic optio quod reiciendis reprehenderit? </li>
  <!-- 3     -->
  <li>Одразу подайте на стіл</li>
  <!-- 4     -->
</ol>
```

как сделать рамку вокруг цифр как на картинке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если верно понял вопрос:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 43px;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
  background-color: green;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  color: yellow;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: -43px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

li {
  /*border: 1px solid #461cff;*/
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover::before {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>На великій сковороді розішруйте рослину олію</li>
  <!-- 1     -->
  <li>У великій мисці змішайте інгрідієнти:
    <!-- 2     -->
    <ol>
      <li>5 тертих картоплин</li>
      <!-- 2.1   -->
      <li>2 яйця</li>
      <!-- 2.2   -->
      <li>1 цибуля </li>
      <!-- 2.3   -->
      <li>3 ст.л борошна</li>
      <!-- 2.4   -->
      <li>сіль і перець за смаком</li>
      <!-- 2.5   -->

    </ol>
  </li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A dolore minima, placeat praesentium quos rem suscipit? Aut cum cumque et hic optio quod reiciendis reprehenderit? </li>
  <!-- 3     -->
  <li>Одразу подайте на стіл</li>
  <!-- 4     -->
</ol>
```